# How to fetch users from an Active Directory Organisational Unit having '//' in its name

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have an Organizational Unit in my Active Directory having '//' in its name for example 'Turbo//Boost'.

and when I try to find users using directory searcher it throws error

> Unknown Error(0x80005000)

Any idea how can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have forward slashes in your OU name, you need to "escape" those characters when searching by prepending them with a backslash.

So try searching for :  `ou=Turbo\/\/Boost` - that should work.

See the [Characters to Escape](http://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm) page by Richard Mueller for a complete list of all "dangerous" characters that need to be escaped in LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bad practice to have // in a AD objects name.
Its also used in netbios names.